# how to get a user confirmation in the middle of a transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, client-server, rabbitmq

I've been working on a transactional services which is used as a part of core banking project. In many services, before inserting any records in my database, I should run several validation on the records. It is also true for editing the records which are already exist in the database.
But sometimes in order to update a record in an specified table, we should change records in other tables which are related to the specified table. Consequently, we need a user confirmation to change records on other tables. But the problem is I don't know how could I get a user confirmation in client while I run a transaction in the server. Is it possible to tackle this problem using sending message between client and server through rabbitMq?
I will be appreciate if any one explain any solution using clear sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I would need to implement this, I would do it in an other way (I do not know if this works for your scenario).

- I would first let the user input his data,
- then I would do a try run and check which additional confirmations are needed I would also save (in the user session) all relevant constraints that are determined while the try run
- then I would ask the user for the additional confirmations determined while the try run
- then I would do the real-run, and use the saved constraint checks to be save that nothing relevant has been changed meanwhile.
- (If there is a relevant change in the data between try- and real-rung detected, I would apologise and start the process with step 2 again)

but this only works if you do not have so many "meanwhile changes"

Comment: Dear @Ralph, thank you in advance to answer my question. Although the solution you suggest is a way to resolve this issue, I myself believe there should be another way to solve my problem in a more appropriate way. I'm not sure, but I think it is better to implement such an event handler using RabbitMQ or other message broker system.

Comment: @moha: of course the are other solutions and it depends on you use case which one is the best for you. But keep in mind what the other solutions mean to your transaction. So if you start an transaction and then ask the user for some input (before closing the transaction) would mean that something in your database might been looked for a long time. -- again it depends on your usecase if this is a problem or not

Comment: I think you are right about the transaction. I have thought about what you said and I think maybe I was totally wrong and should change my analysis. Now, if I change my mind and start the transaction after validation I can postpone the transaction. By which I mean, I can do the validation on the updated record at first and in case I need any confirmation from the user I can get it before start any transaction. Now, what do you suggest? Is there any framework to get confirmation from the client after doing some validations in server?

Comment: @moha: because what you need to implement is almost not reuseable business logic, I do not excpect that there is a framework that solve this out of the box